# Problem running Scrapoxy and Digital Ocean

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrapoxy

I'm trying to run Scrapoxy with Digital Ocean. I successfully created a droplet image and configured Scrapoxy.

When I start Scrapoxy, it keeps on creating a new instance and bypassing max limit. It stops only when it reaches 10 droplets. What annoys me is that No instance found in the GUI version. Also, when I test the proxy server I get this message: "Error: No running instance found". It seems that Scrapoxy only creates droplets and can't connect to them.

I installed Scrapoxy manually. Here is my config file:

```
{
"commander": {
    "password": ".........."
},
"instance": {
    "port": 3128,
    "scaling": {
        "min": 1,
        "max": 2
    }
},
"providers": [
    {
        "type": "digitalocean",
        "token": "5204b9654f301.............c281036bd19e283321c09680ac9c",
        "region": "FRA1",
        "size": "s-1vcpu-1gb",
        "sshKeyName": "scrapoxy",
        "imageName": "forward-proxy",
        "tags": "Proxy,Amazon"
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to put your region in lowercase in the config file

Example:
like this

```
"region": "fra1"
```

instead of

```
"region": "FRA1"
```

There are other troubleshooting steps you could take on the following github pages [Issue 84](https://github.com/fabienvauchelles/scrapoxy/issues/84#issuecomment-458521963) & [Issue 62](https://github.com/fabienvauchelles/scrapoxy/issues/62)